# php-gettext installed but not available

Tags: php, apache2, gettext, php-gettext

I have the following packages installed on Ubuntu 16.04:

- apache2 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1
- php-gettext 1.0.11-2build1
- gettext 0.19.7-2ubuntu3
- php7.0 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4

The only mention of gettext when I call `phpinfo()` is in the module authors section ("GetText = Alex Plotnick"), so I would assume that support has been compiled in correctly.

It seems that gettext isn't loaded properly into PHP, because the following code:

```
<?php

if ( false === function_exists('gettext') ) {
    echo "You do not have the gettext library installed with PHP.";
    exit(1);
}
```

Does indeed print "You do not have the gettext library installed with PHP."

Apart from documentation, the only `php-gettext` files I have installed are:

```
/usr/share/php/php-gettext/gettext.inc
/usr/share/php/php-gettext/streams.php
/usr/share/php/php-gettext/gettext.php
```

I haven't really touched any php or apache config (apart from try and install [icingaweb2](https://github.com/Icinga/icingaweb2))

Can anyone see what my issue could be?

**Update**
More debugging...

```
me@phoenix:~$ ls /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/
10-mysqlnd.ini  20-dom.ini      20-intl.ini  20-mbstring.ini  20-pdo_mysql.ini  20-wddx.ini       20-xmlwriter.ini
15-xml.ini      20-imagick.ini  20-ldap.ini  20-mysqli.ini    20-simplexml.ini  20-xmlreader.ini  20-xsl.ini


me@phoenix:~$ sudo a2dismod php5
ERROR: Module php5 does not exist!


me@phoenix:~$ sudo find / -name gettext.so
/usr/lib/php/20151012/gettext.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22/auto/Locale/gettext/gettext.so
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work out of the box after installation. Have you restarted Apache? Try first `sudo apache2ctl restart` or `sudo service apache2 restart` on the terminal console. If both should not work on your system, try `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`.

Check if there does exist a file `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-gettext.ini` (or similar path on your system) containing the line

```
extension=gettext.so
```

There must **not** be a semicolon prepended, otherwise it is commented out. Some installations may also configue that line within the basic php configuration file `/etc/php/php/7.0/php.ini`, however the debian derivate's way is to use extra files in the `conf.d` folder.

You can enable PHP modules (e.g. gettext) on the command line

```
sudo phpenmod -v 7.0 gettext
```

If this does not work, edit the configuration manually.

Finally restart your Apache service as described above.

Check also if Apache is running the expected PHP version 7.0 with the following line in your PHP page

```
echo phpversion();
```

You can enable / disable Apache2 modules from multiple installed PHP versions on the command line

```
sudo a2dismod php5
sudo a2enmod php7.0
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

Comment: Have restarted. There's no gettext.ini (have added `ls` output to my question). I could edit php.ini but I can't find gettext.so anywhere so I don't think it'd make a difference? The phpenmod command didn't work either. There's no php5 installed so the a2dismod command errors out.

Comment: I manually created a `20-gettext.ini` (it was missing) and it works after restarting - thanks!

Comment: @Catchwa Now since it works, there must be a `gettext.so` somewhere in your library path. You can find files by typing `find / -name gettext.so` on the console. On my system it is located at `/usr/lib/php/20151012/gettext.so`.

Comment: yep, there is - see the bottom of my question :)